# If you shoot rpg in eye hurricane, destory it?

Tags: weather

I been think way to save people by destroy the hurricane.

Answer (score 5):

No.

One way of using physics to see this is to compare orders of magnitude of the involved energies. A RPG payload weighs about 10 kg; [were it completely TNT it would have an energy of about](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TNT_equivalent) 41 Megajoules (it will have less energy since the casing likely makes up a lot of weight, and it might be a slightly different explosive, but this gives us a ballpark figure). It will be released in about $10^{-5}$ seconds (assuming a 10,000 m/s shockwave moving across 10 cm), so the power will be $4.1\times 10^{12}$ Watt.

In the case of hurricanes [estimates](http://www.aoml.noaa.gov/hrd/tcfaq/D7.html) give a total power of $1.5\times 10^{12}$ Watt of wind energy generation and $6\times 10^{14}$ Watt from the cloud/rain formation that drives the system.

So the rpg actually manages to produce more wind energy than the hurricane! ...for $10^{-5}$ seconds. But when the explosive release of energy ends the hurricane will still be there (after all, the explosion is just local). And the driver of the hurricane, the process of taking warm air into the stratosphere, has a power more than a hundred times the rpg.

One can also consider the total energy embodied in air movement. The hurricane force winds are in a region about 150 km across; it is up to 15 km high but most of the air mass is close to the ground. To be a hurricane the wind speed needs to be at least $v=$33 m/s. So a puny hurricane where we count air up to 5 km height (volume $8.8\times 10^{13}$ m$^3$) has a total wind kinetic energy $(1/2)(\rho V)v^2\approx 4.8\times 10^{16}$ Joule. Compare that to the RPG energy; this is 10 billion times larger.

This question is similar to [the frequently asked question about whether we can use nuclear weapons to stop hurricanes](https://news.nationalgeographic.com/2016/11/hurricanes-weather-history-nuclear-weapons/), which has a [long history](https://news.nationalgeographic.com/2016/11/hurricanes-weather-history-nuclear-weapons/). It doesn't work either - nuclear weapons are too small too.